# Secure web service methods

Tags: web-services, token

How to call a web service's methods only through one app?
And other apps can't even use it with a web service address?
I filtered the IP but it didn't work.
An attacker program can be deployed on the same network and the same IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different solutions for authentication. I suggest you to use token based schemes like Bearer authentication.
You can get more info about different HTTP authentication methods at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication
And more info about Bearer scheme at:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.
But the problem is that the attack program can use exactly the same method.Is there a way that only our main program would just use this method?
Or is there a way to distinguish the original program from the attacker program?

Comment: I need a secure channel to connect to APIs that no other application can use.
Even if it succeeds in listening it will not be able to use the sent information.

Comment: You can set a password for initial authentication (login) of your app. Encrypt it with a public key on app side and decrypt with the relevant private key on server side. If the app login request was authenticated then set token in response. The app will use token on every request header.

Comment: Also use Transport Layer Security or SSL for connecting between app and server Api for upper security level. Good luck.